# Expanding Record columns containing SharePoint person/group info

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-collection

I'm trying to create a collection that contains information from a SharePoint person/group column.  So far, I have a few columns of interest added to a column, one of them being the person/group:
[image]

What I would like to do is get the DisplayName from the "NominatedIndividual" column and add it to this same collection.  I've run into various issues trying different methods and now I'm wondering what the best practice is for getting this done.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddColumns`.

**1. Sample data:**

[image]

**2. Code:**

```
AddColumns(colTest,
    "DisplayName", First(ThisRecord.NominatedIndividual).DisplayName,
    "Email", First(ThisRecord.NominatedIndividual).Mail,
    "City", First(ThisRecord.NominatedIndividual).City
)
```